# Finding Final Point using Azimuth and Distance Plugin

Tags: qgis, distance, azimuth

I am new to QGIS, only having used Arc before. I am working for a non-for -profit that is trying to track birds that are viewed from points hiking trails. The GIS intern before me used data on the bearing and distance of birds, and used the "Azimuth and Distance" plug in to create lines pointing to where the birds were. My boss wants these lines turned into single points where the birds were actually located. However, I do not know how to find the terminal point of these lines (the bird's real location) precisely.

So far, I have turned on the nodes of these lines, and found the terminal point, but this forces me to delete all the other nodes that also appear. Is there a plug in I can use to get precise end points for these birds?

Comment: I might be missing something, but bearing and distance alone aren't sufficient to determine a point in 3 dimensions. You need some measure of elevation (meters or angle) above the surface. So, unless you're tracking roadrunners... :)

Comment: If I were able to gain information on the elevation, do you know how I could find the final point on the line that results from the "azimuth and distance" application? Thanks, Underdark!

Comment: Yes, once you have the elevation, you have enough data to compute the point on the surface where the bird is overhead. This should be just a simple Pythagorean theorem application unless the birds are really far away.

Comment: We are not using elevation now. We are showing their location on a 2D model. But we are trying to find a better way to do this as a batch process, rather than using a mathematical equation due to the fact that we have hundreds of points we are working with.